# Oracle: UPDATE JOIN WHERE not working as in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join

Could anyone tell me, how to rewrite the following statement (which works in SQL Server) for Oracle?

```
UPDATE ap SET ap.AccessControlID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM AccessControl WHERE ClientEntityGroupID = apceg.cliententitygroupid)
FROM AccessProfile ap 
JOIN accessprofile_cegroup apceg ON ap.ID = apceg.accessprofileid
WHERE ap.AccessControlID IS NULL
```

It says ORA-00933

> "SQL command not properly ended".
>
> AccessProfile can have 0-n ClientEntityGroups.
>
> AccessControl has 0-1 ClientEntityGroup.
>
> AccessProfile has 0-1 AccessControl.

This is a migration step. Afterwards im deleting the accessprofile_cegroup table so it will be:

```
AccessControl has 0-1 ClientEntityGroup.

AccessProfile has 0-1 AccessControl.
```

This statement sets the `AccessControl` of the first `ClientEntityGroup` of each `AccessProfile`.

Comment: you did put a ; on the end of the statement, right?

Comment: Did you look at my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using MERGE:

```
MERGE INTO AccessProfile ap
USING(SELECT apceg.accessprofileid,MIN(ID) as min_id
      FROM AccessControl ac
      INNER JOIN accessprofile_cegroup apceg 
       ON(ac.ClientEntityGroupID = apceg.cliententitygroupid)
      GROUP BY apceg.accessprofileid) f
 ON(f.accessprofileid = ap.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ap.AccessControlID = f.min_id
WHERE ap.AccessControlID IS NULL
```